# Pygmt : how to fill polygons with cmap color

Tags: python, pygmt

Good morning,

I am using pygmt on python 3.6 with spyder.
I am trying to fill several polygons in a range of colors defined by a colorpalet.
I used makecpt to define the colorpalet.
The variable I want to represent is Mog.

My code is :

```py
pygmt.makecpt(cmap="bilbao",  series=[-5, 50, 5])

for i , long in enumerate(longitude_polyT):     
      fig.plot(x=longitude_polyT[i], y=latitude_polyT[i], frame="a", pen="black", color=Mog[i], cmap=True)
```

But it doesn't fill my polygons.

Does anybody have an idea about it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the issue is because of the color parameter. could you please share the part of the variables with me? `longitude_polyT` , `latitude_polyT` and `Mog`

Comment: Please post the full code so that we can run it and reproduce what you get. If there are any images involved, also post those in links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my best guess at what you want:

```
import pygmt

fig = pygmt.Figure()
a = fig.basemap(region=[0, 6, 0, 2], projection="X12c/4c", frame=True, )

pol = ["n0.9c", "c0.9c", "d0.9c"]
Mog = [
    pygmt.makecpt(cmap="bilbao", series=[-5, 50, 5]),
    pygmt.makecpt(cmap="bilbao", series=[-5, 15, 5]),
    pygmt.makecpt(cmap="bilbao", series=[-8000, 4000])
]
longitude_polyT = [1, 3, 5]
latitude_polyT = [1, 1, 1]

for i, long in enumerate(longitude_polyT):
    fig.plot(x=long, y=latitude_polyT[i], style=pol[i], frame=a,
             pen="black",
             color=Mog[i], cmap=True)
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Couldn't get it to show different colours :(

Answer (score 0):

To color a symbol based on a specific value, you may want to use the `zvalue` parameter together with
`color="+z"` and `cmap=True` of the `pygmt.Figure.plot` method
(for details please see the documentation at https://www.pygmt.org/latest/api/generated/pygmt.Figure.plot.html).

Please find below a code example, modified from the examples posted above. Even this question is already quite old, this answer maybe helps others with a similar question.

*Code example*

```py
import pygmt

# Define variables
pol = ["n0.9c", "c0.9c", "d0.9c"]
lon_polyT = [1, 3, 5]
Mog = [10, -3, 20]

# Create figure object
fig = pygmt.Figure()

# Set up colormap
pygmt.makecpt(cmap="bilbao", series=[-5, 50, 5])

# Make basic map
fig.basemap(
    region=[0, 6, 0, 2],
    projection="X10c/4c",
    frame="a1fg1",
)

# Plot symbols
# https://www.pygmt.org/latest/api/generated/pygmt.Figure.plot.html
for i in range(len(lon_polyT)):
    fig.plot(
        x=lon_polyT[i],
        y=1,
        style=pol[i],  # symbole shape and size
        pen="1p,black",  # outline thickness in points and color
        fill="+z",  # apply to the fill | before PyGMT v0.8.0 "color"
        zvalue=Mog[i],  # value used for color-coding
        cmap=True,  # use colormap set up above
    )

# Show and save figure
fig.show()
# fig.savefig(fname="symbols_color_by_zvalue.png")
```

*Output figure*
[image]